# The POST request is successful, but the data is not added to the database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am writing a site on Flask, I have reached the stage of user registration, but the data from the form are not added to the database, and the post-request is successful, there are no errors.

Here is a script to add to the database

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register_page():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    login = form.login.data
    password = form.password.data
    double_password = form.double_password.data
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hash_password = generate_password_hash(password)
        new_user =User(login=login,password=hash_password)
    try:
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index_page'))
    except:
        return 'ERROR'
    return render_template('register_page.html', title='Registration', form=form)
```

Here is the configuration and connection to the database via Flask-SQLalchemy:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, redirect, jsonify
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sait.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Here is the User class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User> - {self.login}'
```

When I write queries to the database manually, everything is added, and from the form, the data is not added

Comment: I don't see how this code can not add a user row without returning "ERROR".  How do you know the data isn't added?

Comment: The console does not display any error messages after sending data from the form and redirection to the main page is successful. The fact that data is not added I learn from the graphical interface of DB Browser (SQLite), where after I update the database, it remains empty

Comment: If it redirects then it must be writing to _a_ database.  Check that you are inspecting the right database: because SQLite will create a database file if it doesn't already exist, it's a common mistake to inspect one database file but find that the data has been written somewhere else.

Comment: I checked and in a separate file added data to the same database, so they added, but from the site, for some reason are not added

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the submitted form into your form class, otherwise you're loosing your data. [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/wtforms/#in-the-view)

```
from flask import request    

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register_page():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
```

Also, move assigning values to `login`, `password` and `double_password` inside form validation control. Just helps ensure your getting values that are valid. I.e.

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    login = form.login.data
```